# larave looking for file with the old path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have this app from my server, downloaded it, tried to set up on my local for testing but I come across with the error below, where this `/home/cowax/demo.ddman.com` is the old path (server path) and it should show the local path, check everything from .env to config/app.php but unfortunately unable to find the error path. Any help, ideas is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: According to the error message, the error appears to be in `BreadcrumbsServiceProvider.php` on line 94.
did you check `app/Providers/BreadcrumbsServiceProvider.php` ?

Comment: @HassanAzzam this file BreadcrumbsServiceProvider.php does not exist in app/Providerds folder

Comment: Then it must be a third party package, check you installed packages, and if you found it installed then most likely you will find a config file for it inside `config` directory.
if you found the config file then the path might be stored there and you will need to change it.

Comment: @HassanAzzam I'm trying to figure out why its using the server path and not my local path, if its using the local path, probably there will be no error at all

Comment: Actually i found the package, and you should find a config file in `config/breadcrumbs.php` there you will find an array of files, you should find the server path there and you will need to change it to your local path.

Comment: I think the problem is that you downloaded the whole laravel app with it's server configurations, that's why it's not working.
try deleting the package config file `config/breadcrumbs.php` and then run 
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=breadcrumbs-config` than should fix it

Comment: deleting the bootstrap/cache and then run  php artisan config:cache solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Found at `bootstrap/cache/config.php`, running `php artisan config:clear` wont work first, it needs the `bootstrap/cache/*` to be deleted first then perform `php artisan config:clear`